# How many demonstrative pronouns are there really?

Tags: pronouns, demonstratives, obscure-terms

Are there only four demonstrative pronouns *this*, *that*, *these*, and *those* in English, or are there more like *thik* which is a variation of *this* and *that*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *“Hither, page, and stand by me
>
>           If thou know’st it, telling
>
>   **Yonder** peasant, who is he?
>
>           Where and what his dwelling?”*
>
> “Sire, he lives a good league hence
>           Underneath the mountain
>   Right against the forest fence
>           By Saint Agnes’ fountain.”

The simple answer is that no, the only standard ones are *this, that, these, those*.
But I suppose the more nuanced answer depends on the meaning you ascribe to *demonstrative*, and perhaps even to *be*.

The OED says demonstratives are:

> A word used to indicate the location (spatially, temporally, or abstractly) of something or someone in relation to the discourse context; esp. a demonstrative pronoun or determiner (as, in English, *this, that, these, those*). Formerly also more generally: †a word used to indicate the person or thing referred to (as, for example, a personal pronoun or a determiner) (*obsolete*).
>
> - 1768   A. Vieyra *New Portuguese Gram*. 35  — There are three principal demonstratives in Portuguese, viz. *este*, this; *esse*, that; *aquelle*, that.
> - 1833   L. J. A. McHenry *Spanish Gram*. 42   Possessives and demonstratives are used in Spanish both as adjectives and as pronouns.
> - 1875   R. Morris *Hist. Eng. Gram*. (1877) 114   The Demonstratives are *the, that, this, such, so, same, yon*.
> - 1911   F. Boas Handbk. *Amer. Indian Langs*. (U.S. Bureau Amer. Ethnol. Bull. No. 40) I. 949   Demonstratives are usually adverbialized by means of another particle.
> - 1995   C. E. Schweitzer in F. W. Carové *Kinderleben* 52   Carové..continues with a phrase in which the initial *das* is a demonstrative.

The reason the sense of *be* matters is that whatever others you may find are apt to **be** one or more of obsolete, archaic, dialectal, or regional in nature, and so of only limited use today.

## *yon, yond, yonder*

The most obvious example is ***yon***, which is a demonstrative determiner for something far away but in sight, and can be roped into use as a demonstrative pronoun for the same. It also has variants ***yond*** and ***yonder***, but no matter which way you spell it, it’s no longer in common use throughout the entire anglosphere.

> Now *archaic* and *dialect*.
>
> A. *adj*.
>
> 1. A demonstrative word used to modify a noun to indicate a thing or person as (literally, or sometimes mentally) pointed out: cf. *that* adj. 1. Formerly often, as still in some dialects, simply equivalent to *that* (*those*); but chiefly, and in later literary use almost always, referring to a visible object at a distance but within view: = ‘that (those)…over there’. Also in *yon same*.
>
> B. *pron*. *singular* or *plural*.
>
> The adjective used absol., usually denoting a visible object (or objects) pointed out, at a distance but within view: = ‘that (or those) over there’; but sometimes simply = ‘that’ (or ‘those’): cf. A. 1. Now only *Scottish* and *dialect*.

To me, it has a rustic feel to it, something from the 19th century or from rural or mountain folk.

## *thilk*

Your other example of *thik* is less known, at least cisatlantically. It comes out of Middle English and has had several spellings. It can be found in the OED under ***thilk*** *adj.* and *pron.*

> **Pronunciation**: /ðɪlk/
>
> **Etymology**: Middle English *þilke*, known a1300; apparently < *þe*, the adj., pron.2, and n.1 + *ilce, ilk* adj.1, pron.1, and n. same, meaning the or that same; in some of the quots. *þe ilke* or *þet ilke* occurs as a MS. variant.
>
> This analysis suits the form *þilke*, but does not explain the early southern *þülke* and the Kentish *þelke*, which naturally indicate an Old English **þylce*. Can there have been a confusion in the south between *þilke* and late Old English *þylc* *for* *þyllic, thellich* adj. and pron.?
>
> (*Thick* /ðɪk/ is in dialect use from Cornwall and Hants to Worcester and Hereford; and also in Pembroke, Glamorgan, and Wexford. In many parts it has also the form *thicky*, *thickee*, or *thicka*. It generally means ‘that’, but in some parts ‘this’, in which case it is contrasted with *thuck, thock*, or *thack* = that. It is sometimes indefinite, and has to be made definite, as *thick* here, this, *thick* there, that. In Somerset and Dorset, *thick* and *theäse* are used only of individual shaped things, as a man or tree, while *that* and *this* are used of formless substances in the mass, as flour, milk, marble. See *Eng. Dial. Dict*.)
>
> *archaic* or *dialect*.
>
> A. *adj*.
>
> a. (determiner). The very (thing, person, etc.) mentioned or indicated; the same; that; this.
>
> †b. With plural n.: These; those. *Obsolete.*
>
> B. *pron*.
>
> a. That (or this) person or thing.
>
> †b. plural. Those. *Obsolete*.

So there are only four demonstrative pronouns in common use today. There are a few other stray forms held over from Middle English that you may find in extremely old writing or in dialect — or in Scotland. :)

## *thon*

From the [Scots Learners' Grammar](http://scotshaunbuik.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/SHGremmar-1.4.1.pdf),

> > Scots has two extra forms **thon** and yon to refer to things more distant from both speakers. **Thon** seems to be between that and yon both spatially and linguistically.

Thon can translate as that or those.

Comment: And of course the dialect or uneducated variant of “them” (or them there) for “those”. (Have I been here before with “them there”? Seem to remember getting slated for it.)

Comment: Sometimes above, below, LHS, RHS get used as such.

Comment: Thon is in current use in parts of Scotland, including Orkney. Edited to include.