# Are there any old third-person singular pronouns the way “thou” is an old second-person pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, archaicisms

[***Thou***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou) is an old ***second***-person singular pronoun in English.

Are there any old ***third***-person singular pronouns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Personal Pronouns: Rustic *hisn* and *hern*, *hit* and *sho*

Because [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Old_English_personal_pronouns_(table)) and [Middle English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English#Pronouns) each had their own sets of pronouns that differ from ours,
let’s restrict this to Modern English only, not anything earlier like *The
Canterbury Tales* or *Sir Gawain and the Green Knight*, respectively from
two different branches of Middle English.

Otherwise we’d have to discuss
things like the pronoun *hit* that we now spell without the leading *h-*
these days outside of various regional dialects. English dialects do preserve a tremendous wealth of such ancient forms that are still used in dialect speech. For example:

> - **1993**   *New Shetlander* Sept. 29
>      Hit’s a notion shu’s taen lately.

There *hit* means *it* and *shu* (or *sho*) means *she*. There are many, **many** more of these that you come across from time to time.

Even so, we can still find other archaic personal pronouns that persist today
only in dialect, not in standard English. The most notable of these is probably the *-n* genitives formed by analogy
with *mine* and *thine*, including ***hisn, hern, theirn, ourn, yourn***.
The one that goes with *his* has many spellings, being non-standard. These
include *hisn, his’n, hisen, hissen, hizzen*.

The [paywalled OED gives as the etymology of ***hisn***](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87250?redirectedFrom=hisn#eid):

> #### Alteration of *his* adj. after *mine* pron., *thine* pron. Compare *hern* pron.1, *hern* pron.2, *theirn* pron., *ourn* pron., *yourn* pron., and compare also *hisis* pron.
>
> *Eng. Dial. Dict.* records the word from Yorkshire and Lancashire and
> widely from the midlands and south of England; *Surv. Eng. Dial.* records the
> word from the majority of midland and southern counties, with the exception
> of Cheshire to the north, Rutland, Norfolk, Kent, and Sussex to the east,
> and Dorset, Devon, and Cornwall to the west. *Dict. Amer. Regional Eng.*
> records the word chiefly from New England and southern and south Midland
> states.
>
> Compare also English and U.S. regional *hisn’s*, pronoun and adjective
> (19th cent.).

These started in Late Middle English, and made the transition into Early
Modern English.  However, they were never really considered part of
standard English, and modern writers have used them only to represent
the speech characteristic of various regional dialects, where they still exist to this day.  The OED says that
*hisn* is:

> #### Now *English regional* (*midlands and southern*) and *U.S. regional* (chiefly *south Midland, southern,* and *New England*).

They give genitive examples corresponding to *mine* and *thine*, including these later ones:

> - **1867**   ‘M. Twain’ *Celebrated Jumping Frog* 15   
>   It always makes me feel sorry when I think of that last fight of his’n.
> - **1930**   W. Faulkner *As I lay Dying* 115   
>   He don’t say nothing; just looks at me with them queer eyes of hisn that makes folks talk.
> - **1938**   W. E. Railey *Hist. Woodford County* ii. 55/1   
>   I trust the old mill will be to ‘him and hisn’ a sacred trust.
> - **1946**   L. Lenski *Blue Ridge Billy* viii. 108   
>   I’ve got more baskets than I can sell in a month of Sundays. Uncle Pozy come by here t’other day..and wished all his’n on me.
> - **1983**   E. McClanahan *Nat. Man* (1984) iii. 22   
>   Old Nobs thinks this new boy of his’n is gonna be shit on a stick, don’t he?
> - **2011**   S. Rodriguez *Weight of Light* iii. 36   
>   My tongue feel thick and swole like hisn, and I can’t speak.

They also give possessive examples corresponding to *my* and *thy* of which these are just the more recent:

> - **1910**   C. E. Mulford *Hopalong Cassidy* xx. 130   
>   Taking the button and looking it over. ‘Yep, it’s hissn, all right.’
> - **1923**   ‘R. Crompton’ *William Again* x. 179   
>   Well it isn’t his’n—it’s stole stuff.
> - **1995**   M. L. Settle *Choices* ɪ. vi. 76   
>   He’s got seven kids, four of them hissen.
> - **2004**   J. B. Rehder *Appalachian Folkways* 297   
>   That plate is hern... But the cup is hisn.

Notice how these examples are almost all meant to represent the rustic speech of regional dialects.

## Demonstrative Pronouns: *yon*, *thon*, *thilk*

Another source of archaic pronouns still occasionally heard is the demonstrative pronouns beyond the four standard ones *this, that, those, these*. These include [*yon, yond, yonder, thilk, thon*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/514638/2085).

Comment: *The most notable of these is probably the -n genitives formed by analogy with mine and thine, including hisn, hern, theirn, ourn, yourn.* These are phrases - they are contractions for "his one" or "his ones" (his'ns), etc. As a native speaker of East Midlands English, I heard (and still hear when I am there) "his one" (pron "his un") for emphasis.

Comment: @Greybeard Once whilom phrases like *be-hind* and *be-fore* and *be-yond* and *a-sleep* and *a-shore* and *now-a-days* and *to-day* and *to-morrow* become fully lexicalized, they no longer count as phrases. So for example, *yinz* is still a second-person plural pronoun **not** a phrase, even though it derives from earlier *ye-ones*. In any event, notice how the OED gives more weight to the survival of *hisn* and *hern* due to analogy with *mine* and *thine* than they do to any anterior phrasal derivation.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, his'n, etc. has not made the transition that mine and thine have. I feel that it is unlikely to as it is dialect and has no standard spelling. The OED entry as "his'n" is just that - his'n with apostrophe. "to day" is a prepositional phrase, but today is an adverb. It also does not account for "his un/one", nor why "his" pronoun is interchangeable even among those who speak the dialect.

Comment: @Greybeard I see no mention of region or register or currency or “acceptability” or derivation or period in the question. Do you?

Comment: Your answer includes it. The question is "Are there any old third-person singular pronouns?" My response is that His'n, etc., are not pronouns but phrases as the "**'n**" can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

No.

*Thee* and *thou* correspond to the French *tu*, and similar second person singular pronouns in other European languages, which are used for intimates, children and animals while the plural form is reserved for addressing people politely. In English, for some reason, we long ago started using the plural *you* for everyone and *thou* fell out of use except in traditional prayers and some dialects.

This doesn't affect the first and third person at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thou/thee/thy/thine are exceptions in that they survived into Modern English and can still be heard (albeit rarely or in religious contexts). There were old third-person pronouns in both Old English and Middle English, but none of them survived into Modern English other than the ones we have.